# Add a new field to my datagrid input based on another datagrid input

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I have a input DataGrid called "input_projects" with the following fields:

- id (Integer)
- typeCode (String)

And another datagrid called "input_types" with the list of types:

- id (Integer)
- name (String)
- code (String)

Then, i need to create a new field in my "input_projects" with the "id" of the each type.

I don't know how to do this, in pseudo-code it could be something like this:

```
foreach(projects as project) {
   foreach(types as type) {
       if(project.typeCode == type.code) {
           project.typeId = type.id;
       }
   }
}
```

How is it possible to do this in pentaho?

Comment: so you want to join both tables based on 'input_projects' typeCode = 'input_types' code ? Correct ?

Comment: yes. Is there a join step?

Comment: @CristianCurti Thanks! I use the step "Join rows" and it was worth! :) If you want you can create a reply for validate the question.

Comment: You can answer your own question, guiding on how you came to the conclusion of the matter, that is even more important for the community i think :)